# How to stop updating the UI when app is on pause?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

How can I stop the UI from being updated when the user clicks on the menu button?
Do i clear the function when the pause event gets triggered like so?

```
var ready = document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
    document.body.innerHTML('hello world');
    // rest of the code
}, false);

var pause = document.addEventListener('pause', function(){
  document.body.innerHTML = '';
}, false);
```

Comment: With `document.body.innerHTML = '';` you are removing all the dom, so page should be empty. What do you mean UI from being updated?

Comment: @GibboK I wrote `document.body.innerHTML` as an example only. What I meant was to stop the app UI from being updated when the app is on 'pause'. To stop ajax calls etc.

Comment: yeah but i want the ajax to re-run when device ready gets fired again. Force ajax to sleep on pause event and run on resume/ready @GibboK